Synthesis of Mg(CH2Ph)2
Sometimes called Dibenzylmagnesium, I have found it referenced in various papers on google scholar, but I am not certain of its mp, bp, and synthesis route. Please advise.

For synthesis see, for example, section 2.2 from https://doi.org/10.1002/macp.201300710 and reference therein.

@andselisk That is very helpful! Now all I need it to purify it. Also the reference therein cited is in French.

I don't think you can find melting point and boiling point of dibenzylmagnesium $(\ce{Mg(C6H7)2})$, because reactivity and stability of it is compatible with those of Grignard reagents, if not more reactive (setup of these reactions are always used Schlenk line to avoid contact with moisture and air). To my knowledge, most of the time it's prepared in situ as explained in Ref. 1:

Reaction of Dibenzylmagnesium with Pyridine.—The benzylmagnesium chloride was prepared exactly as described before. Then $\pu{150 ml.}$ of freshly purified$^8$ dioxane was added to the Grignard reagent and the mixture was stirred for 30 minutes. To this suspension was added dropwise $\pu{64 g.}$ $(\pu{0.8 mole})$ of anhydrous pyridine after which the mixture was refluxed on a steam-cone for 24 hours with constant stirring.

It is clear that etherification of benzylmagnesium chloride with dioxane $(\ce{C4H8O2})$ make the etherate of $\ce{Mg(C6H7)2}$, as $\ce{Mg(C6H7)2.2C4H8O2}$ in situ. It is note worthy that the yield difference between the reaction of pyridine and benzylmagnesium chloride (crude yield: 8%) and the reaction of pyridine and dibenzylmagnesium (crude yield: 32%) to give mixture of 2- and 4-benzylpyridines is huge. The only difference between two reactions are the addition of $\pu{150 mL}$ of dioxane before addition of Grignard reagent.
This is pure speculation, but the structure of dibenzylmagnesium is probably resemblance that of ferrocene $(\ce{FeCp2})$, because electronic distribution of benzyl anon is similar to cyclopentadiene anion. As a matter of fact, magnesium make structurally similar magnesocene $(\ce{MgCp2})$ with cyclopentadine (Ref. 2), which shows the equilibrium between the corresponding Grignard reagent $(\ce{CpMgX})$ and dialkyl magnesium $(\ce{MgCp2})$:

Accordingly, the preparation method via Grignard reagent requires the synthesis of Grignard reagents first and subsequently the metalation reaction, similar way that has done in Ref. 1:


References:

Robert A. Benkeser and Dexter S. Holton, "The Reaction of Benzylmagnesium Chloride and Dibenzylmagnesium with Pyridine," J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1951, 73(12), 5861–5862 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01156a503).
Philipp Schüler, Helmar Görls, Sven Krieck, and Matthias Westerhausen, "One-Step Synthesis and Schlenk-Type Equilibrium of Cyclopentadienylmagnesium Bromides," " Chemistry—A European Journal 2021, 27(62), 15508-15515 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1002/chem.202102636).

